# Collidestart not fired - Aframe 1.4.1 & Ammo.js with 8th wall

Tags: game-physics, aframe, ammo.js, 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I want to detect collisions between dynamically created falling boxes and the ground. After the collision, a highscore increases & the boxes are removed from the scene.

Problem:
Some boxes don't collide correctly, i.e. "collidestart" isn't fired in this case. Can somebody help me and have an advice for my problem?

I used Aframe 1.4.1 and ammo.js to detect the collisions.

body.html

```
<a-scene
  game-logic
  xrextras-runtime-error
  renderer="colorManagement:true"
  physics="driver: ammo; debug: true; gravity: 0, -1, 0"
  xrweb="allowedDevices: any; defaultEnvironmentFloorScale: 0.4">

  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="green-box" src="./assets/green-box.glb"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>

  <a-camera id="camera" position="0 20 32"> </a-camera>

  <a-entity
    light="
      type: directional;
      intensity: 0.8;
      castShadow: true;
      shadowMapHeight:2048;
      shadowMapWidth:2048;
      shadowCameraTop: 20;
      shadowCameraBottom: -20;
      shadowCameraRight: 20;
      shadowCameraLeft: -20;
      target: #camera"
    xrextras-attach="target: camera; offset: 0 15 0"
    position="1 4.3 2.5"
    shadow>
  </a-entity>

  <a-light type="ambient" intensity="0.5"></a-light>

  <a-box
    id="ground"
    box-collide
    scale="1000 2 1000"
    position="0 -1 0"
    material="shader: shadow; transparent: true; opacity: 0.4"
    ammo-body="type: static; emitCollisionEvents: true;"
    ammo-shape="type: box"
    shadow>
  </a-box>
</a-scene>
```

logic.js

```
  init() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.addElements()
    }, 4000)
  },

  addElements() {

    const newElement = document.createElement('a-entity')
    const randomX = Math.random() * 10
    const randomZ = -(Math.random() * 10)
    const landingPoint = {x: randomX, y: 32, z: randomZ}
    newElement.setAttribute('position', landingPoint)
    const randomXRotation = Math.random() * 360
    const randomYRotation = Math.random() * 360
    const randomZRotation = Math.random() * 360
    newElement.setAttribute('rotation', `${randomXRotation} ${randomYRotation} 0 `)
    newElement.setAttribute('visible', 'false')
    newElement.setAttribute('scale', '3 3 3')
    newElement.setAttribute('shadow', {
      receive: false,
    })
    newElement.setAttribute('gltf-model', '#green-box')
    document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(newElement)

    newElement.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {

      newElement.setAttribute('visible', 'true')
      let didCollide = false

      setTimeout(() => {
        newElement.setAttribute('ammo-body', {
          type: 'dynamic',
          mass: 200,
          emitCollisionEvents: true,
        })
        newElement.setAttribute('ammo-shape', {
          type: 'hull',
        })
      }, 200)

      newElement.addEventListener('collidestart', (e) => {
        console.log('collidestart --> not fired fired for every a-entity ', e)

        if (!didCollide && e.detail.targetEl.body.el.id === 'ground') {
          didCollide = true

          setTimeout(() => {
            if (newElement.parentNode) {
              newElement.parentElement.removeChild(newElement)
            } 
          }, 800)
        }
      })
    })
  },
```